# High and low beams swapped after lens replacement (2006 Dodge RAM)

Tags: headlight

When I replaced my new lenses on my 2006 Dodge Ram 1500, the high and low beam got swapped. How could this happen? What did I do wrong? The plugs only can be plugged in one way.

Comment: Did you replace them with stock or an aftermarket mod, like halo lights, that require some conversion wiring?

Comment: Andy when you say lenses, what do you mean? Did you change the whole assembly?